# How to correctly encrypt data with proper authentication using AES-256-CBC in php?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have been using the openssl function for encrypting data with AES-256-CBC in php. I have been able to encrypt it using an unique IV (by generating with    openssl_random_pseudo_bytes)for each new encryption.

But I am struggling with the idea of authenticated encryption with aes cbc. How do I basically authenticate when I am about to decrypt the data?

Do I need to use something like PBKDF2, blowfish or hash_hmac()?

Do I need to hash the key somehow?

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php) which is available for php and many other languages. See this [ReadMe](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) for implementation details.

Even if you don't use RNCryptor the methods are correct and secure.

Some details from the site:

- AES-256 encryption
- CBC mode
- Password stretching with PBKDF2
- Password salting
- Random IV
- Encrypt-then-hash HMAC
- Versioning

Comment: The PHP version of RNCryptor was susceptible to remote timing attacks and type confusion bugs for almost a year after it was reported to the team on Github and posted to Full Disclosure. I would strongly encourage anyone who even *thinks* of deploying it to consult with a crypto expert for `$languageOfChoice` first. The other language implementations might not be safe.

Comment: While all of that is true it does not help with an answer. The developers who come here for help generally have little to no knowledge about encryption and cryptographic security, they generally just want to encrypt something as quickly and easily as possible without having to learn anything about encryption, much less about security. If the answer is how to correctly use the primitives in a secure scheme they in general will not be capable, much less implement it securely.

Comment: ... Sure, the peer review of RNCryptor in all it's languages could be better but that is not easy, even mainstream libraries like OpenSSL had major issues such as Heartbleed. IMO suggesting RNCryptor is a win for the developers asking here, they will be much better off than writing their own implementations. RNCryptor is not the answer for all uses and/or developers, in particular knowledgeable developers will probably write their own solution that more closely meet their requirements—and may well contain similar errors. Personally I have my security code reviewed by a SME.

Comment: Here's the flipside: The RNCryptor team took *almost a year* to apply a trivial security fix. The team behind it is either asleep at the wheel (not paying attention) or negligent. Neither is good.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Your recommendation for OP? Oh, the time from report to fix was 6 months (Jun 9 to Dec 6), *almost a year* is stretching things. I agree that the time to a fix was longer than it should ideally be.

Comment: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-C/blob/master/rncryptor_c.c#L429 STOP RECOMMENDING THIS INSECURE LIBRARY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101539/discussion-between-scott-arciszewski-and-zaph).

Answer (score 1):

> But I am struggling with the idea of authenticated encryption with aes cbc. How do I basically authenticate when I am about to decrypt the data?

After you encrypt the data with a random IV, put both the ciphertext and IV into `hash_hmac()` with a second key.

If you're asking because you need to deploy into production, wait until version 2 of [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) is released and use that instead. (It's AES-256-CTR not AES-256-CBC, but CTR mode has less attack surface than CBC mode; i.e. no padding oracle attacks if you defeat the HMAC.)

#### Don't use RNCryptor.

RNCryptor is/was not written in accordance to [cryptography coding standards](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-C/blob/ca238ab862205abdcb2e2ae173d2695037639154/rncryptor_c.c#L429), neither in [PHP](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php/blob/f7ab514209fe476c4aa83a1df1fe9bb655e9e9b0/lib/RNCryptor/Decryptor.php#L99), nor in [Python](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-python/blob/71031f243bcba2aaa7bca4ff9a4c01358427b476/RNCryptor.py#L87).

RNCryptor literally [violates rule 1 of the cryptography coding standards](https://cryptocoding.net/index.php/Coding_rules#Compare_secret_strings_in_constant_time) consistently. There may be other issues that have yet been undiscovered. If you want portability across languages, [use libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application).

Comment: CTR mode is difficult to get correct with the nonce requirement, Microsoft has gotten that wrong at least a couple of times. CBC in itself does not have a padding attack, if the implementation does not return padding errors there is no Padding Oracle.

Comment: CTR nonce reuse vs CBC IV reuse is equally difficult to implement safely, although their impacts are drastically different. CTR mode turns your block cipher into a stream cipher, which reduces the attack surface by removing padding entirely.

Comment: Scott, you know the consequences of a reused nonce and key combination in CTR mode. Two messages with the same nounce and key combination  can expose the xor stream and that can be used to decrypt any further messages encrypted with the same nonce and key combination. CBC mode does not have that problem and padding does not provide an attack vector, a Padding Oracle does.

Comment: And a padding oracle requires not authenticating the ciphertext. Or a timing side-channel that allows forgeries.