# Strategy for generating and saving password for encryption and decryption

Tags: ios, cryptography, aes, keychain, rncryptor

I'm using the `RNEncryptor` and `RNDecryptor` classes for encryption and decryption as follows:

```
NSData *encryptedData = [RNEncryptor encryptData:input
                                    withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                        password:thePassword
                                           error:nil];

NSData *output = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData
                             withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                                 password:thePassword
                                    error:nil];
```

The first time I have to encrypt data in my app I generate a password using the `RNCryptor` class as follows:

```
NSData *thePasswordData = [RNCryptor randomDataOfLength:32];
NSString *thePassword = [aesPasswordData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

I save this generated password in the app's Keychain and use it for all subsequent encryption and decryption.

Is this a good strategy for encryption/decryption or can anyone see any flaws in it? Should I instead be generating an AES key and storing that in the Keychain and working with that rather than a password?

**Edit:** I changed above how I generate the password from using the `NSProcessInfo` class to using the `RNCryptor` class based on Rob Napier's answer. That aside I'm still curious to know whether the strategy in general of working with a password rather than an AES key is correct and secure.

Comment: `globallyUniqueString` or a `NSUUID` is ok, but nothing beats asking the user for a good password

Comment: Thanks for the response Wain. I need for this to happen seamlessly... without user interaction. Hence why I'm having to generate a random string.

Comment: @Wain But how can one trust the user to provide a good password? "Passw0rd" will pass most tests, 8 characters, at least one uppercase letter and one number yet is far from a good password.

Comment: @zaph user entered passwords can be weak, but not having the password stored on the device makes the encryption a lot harder to undo

Comment: @Wain True but the question is not about a a user generated password. I also find issue with an assumption that a user can supply a "good password". If user passwords are going to be accepted there are other things that must be handled such as rate limiting attempts. There are substantial UI issues requiring a user to enter a password repetitively that may well not be acceptable. The comment would be better as an answer complete with appropriate caveats.

Comment: @zaph indeed there are issues and it was a very general comment, the key really is that storing the encryption password on the device is a bad idea and I didn't mention that originally. If the priority is security then often you have to accept user inconvenience to achieve it. For iOS, brute force is of very limited capability, you'd need to do a lot of work to have an automated brute force attack, most people will get bored long before manually cracking even a mediocre user password.

Comment: @Wain Sure, a brute force attack is not that easy but I have seen it accomplished with LEGOs. In a similar way retrieving a key from the keychain is difficult and requires technical knowledge and skill. If the user has a passcode the back off quickly becomes one attempt per hour and if set to erase after 10 attempts it seems that is very secure, ask the FBI. We have locks on our house doors yet have breakable windows, we are content with trading some amount of security for convenience and/or aesthetics. As my SME says all of security is just is just increasing the work factor.

Comment: @zaph agreed. interesting technique using LEGO.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way to pick a password. `globallyUniqueString` can be quite predictable in many of its bits. You're much better off using something like `RNCryptor.randomDataOfLength` to generate a blob of desired length (32 bytes would be ideal), and then base-64 encode it to get a password.

Using `randomDataOfLength` to generate keys instead wouldn't really be any more secure, but it would be faster (by 10s of milliseconds depending on the device, if that matters to you). In general, I recommend using the password interface unless you have a special problem where keys are particularly helpful. Keys are just a little harder to use correctly.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the response. Pleasure! :-) I didn't realise that the `RPCryptor` library had a method for generating random data. I've updated my code and my question above to use this. That aside, I'm guessing based on your answer that working with passwords and the app's Keychain is a good strategy and I shouldn't need to work with keys directly?

Comment: Also available from Apple are [`arc4random_buf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) and [`SecRandomCopyBytes()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007281-CH5-SW3).

Comment: Yep; `randomDataOfLength` is just an objc wrapper around `SecRandomCopyBytes`. If you already have RNCryptor imported, it's handy.

Answer (score 1):

The actual encryption key used by these libs is derived from the password, if you use one, but, IIRC, salted so it isn't intrinsically less secure.

There are concerns regarding the theoretical level of security provided by these libraries, (see [How to correctly encrypt data with proper authentication using AES-256-CBC in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954998/how-to-correctly-encrypt-data-with-proper-authentication-using-aes-256-cbc-in-ph/34969963#34969963)) but you have to make a judgement call on that. Thing to bear in mind is that RNCryptor is a set of libraries (which may have published attack vectors in different implementations) AND a consistent format, which is useful if you want to move encrypted data across platforms.

Personally, I would feel more comfortable with using a unique, random AES key for each encryption and storing that key encrypted with RSA stored in the keychain.

Comment: Thanks for the response J.B. I'll definitely take this into consideration and will re-evaluate whether I should work with keys directly and whether the RNCryptor library offers the security I need.

Comment: Of course, if you use a fresh key every time you encrypt something (e.g. with RNCryptor), then you limit any successful attack on that key to that specific blob. Plus, the asymmetric crypto (RSA) is much easier to work with IME ...